# Out of range value for float

Tags: mysql, database

```
INSERT INTO emp (emp_name,emp_age,emp_designation,emp_salary,status,orate,rate,hours,total,tax)
VALUES ('Abishek',24,'Consultant',10000,'Married',0021.500,21.00,24,12000,200);
```

I'm getting these errors

```
Out of range value column 'orate' at row 1
```

while my table is:

[image]

Comment: `orate float(8,4)`

Answer (score 5):

Read the [mysql doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/floating-point-types.html):

> MySQL permits a nonstandard syntax: FLOAT(M,D) or REAL(M,D) or DOUBLE
> PRECISION(M,D). Here, (M,D) means than values can be stored with up to
> M digits in total, of which D digits may be after the decimal point.

So 5,4 means 5 total values and up to 4 after the decimal Point

So you can only have one digit before the decimal point

Comment: Just as a note, I'm wondering why leading zeroes are not ignored in that case, since the input `0021.500` should fit in the type `float(5,4)` theoretically!?

Comment: @xander No. because you can only have one digit before the dot and up to 4 Digits after

Comment: oh yeah you're right I totally missed there are only 3 digits after the dot in the example.

Comment: @xander it doesn't matter. Also 21.5 is out of range